# Get 403 when trying to make post request to controller endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

Summary: I want users who are not logged in to be able to make a post request to a certain endpoint, `/users/registration/create` specifically. I've tried to configure my security filter chain to permit requests to `/users/registration/**`. I can make a GET request to `/users/registration/form`, fill out the fields, and then click submit. When I submit the form (to `/users/registration/create`), the browser responds with a 403.

I have the following configuration:

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                .requestMatchers( "/users/registration/**").permitAll()
            );
        return http.build();
    }
```

I can load `/users/registration/form` in my browser just fine, but once I submit the form, which sends the data to `/users/registration/create`, I get a 403 as a response.

In case it's needed...

Here's my controller:

```
@Controller
public class UserRegistrationsController {
    @Autowired
    private AppUserService appUserService;

    @GetMapping("/users/registration/form")
    public String newRegistration(WebRequest request, Model model) {
        AppUserDto appUserDto = new AppUserDto();
        model.addAttribute("user", appUserDto);
        return "users/registration";
    }

    @PostMapping("/users/registration/create")
    public void createRegistration(
        @ModelAttribute("user") @Valid AppUserDto appUserDto,
        HttpServletRequest request,
        Errors errors
    ) {
        try {
            AppUser registered = appUserService.registerNewUserAccount(appUserDto);
        } catch (AppUserAlreadyExistsException ex) {

        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Not sure if this is the right way to do it, but I tried disabling CSRF and doing the same request again:

```
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> {
            authorize.requestMatchers("/", "/users/registration/**").permitAll();
        });
        http.csrf().disable();
        return http.build();
    }
```

Comment: Are you sending the CSRF Token with the request? If you are not sure, whether CSRF is related to it, deactivate CSRF with `http.csrf().disable()` temporarily and try to send your request again.

Comment: @AlexR I disabled CSRF and tried the same request again, still getting a 403. I updated my question with the code I added. It looks like it might be because my code is trying to render a template that doesn't exist.